# Remove indentation for items of not the same level in a list

Tags: lists, indentation, enumerate

I need to make a list look like this:

a) First level item

b) First level item

1° Second level item

2° Second level item

Instead of what is obtained by this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumii}$^{\circ}$}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First level item
\item First level item
\begin{enumerate}
\item Second level item
\item Second level item
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you load the `enumitem` package, you just need to pass `leftmargin=0cm` to the second list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumii}$^{\circ}$}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First level item
\item First level item
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0cm] % <-- here
\item Second level item
\item Second level item
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to do this for all lists in your document, place the command

```
\setlist[enumerate, 2]{leftmargin=0cm}
```

in your preamble. This tells `enumitem` to apply the specified setting to the 2<sup>nd</sup> nested level of all `enumerate` lists:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumii}$^{\circ}$}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate, 2]{leftmargin=0cm} % <-- here
\begin{document}
First list.
\begin{enumerate}
\item First level item
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Second level item
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
Second list.
\begin{enumerate}
\item First level item
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Second level item
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]